# How to include jQuery in an iframe without re-linking it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Simple question, how can I use the `$` jQuery object in an iframe without re-linking the jQuery source?

I've tried something simple like this:

```
var $ = top.jQuery();
```

but I'm sure it is a little more involved than that.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it within the same domain? If not then you'll run into browser security issues and you'll need to re-include it?

Comment: No, everything is on the same domain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do call it with `var $ = parent.$` and it works fine in our web app.

You must not put the parenthesis at the end.

Comment: @Daniel, English as a second language makes you pass over these "nuances" :)

Comment: Yes, this appears to work, however it seems the context of it is attached to the parent window.  Is this normal?  Ie, I can only select elements from the parent window, not the iframe.

Comment: You need to declare the iframe context like `$('#hey',window.document)` when using `$` inside the iframe

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
var $ = window.parent.$;
```

That should do it